# Does browser 'view-source' mode avoid scripting attacks?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

Let's say there's a URL `www.badjs.com` which is untrusted and may contain bad scripts.

Intuitively, a [view-source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme) navigation to that URL does not execute any scripts so it should be safe. It would at least allow me to inspect the source safely.

But intuition is a terrible way to draw conclusions on security issues, so my question is:

Is view-source a safe way to look at a website from a js script injection perspective?

Comment: Just as bugs in the JS implementation might be vulnerable to attacks, so too might the source renderer, syntax highlighter, etc. Of course, the attack surface is smaller, but it's still larger than wget or curl, and even those might have vulnerabilities.

Comment: alternatively, you can do `curl http://url.ext` from the terminal, but some websites might not serve proper markup to non-browser user-agents, so you will have to spoof your UA with `curl -A "user-agent-here" http://url`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely safe (in Google Chrome) to open an untrusted website in `view-source` mode. The key point to note here is that you should "open" the page in `view-source` mode, meaning you *should not allow any rendering to happen* by normally loading the webpage first and then viewing the source.

An example in Google Chrome would be `view-source:http://www.badjs.com/`

By design, Google Chrome will initiate a new GET request to the server and provide the client browser with the unrendered version of the webpage when in `view-source` mode.

You could also use a No-Script extension or add-on for your specific browser to prevent any scripting attacks.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was exactly what I meant: navigate directly to the `view-source` prefixed URL.

Comment: Edited the answer for more clarity. I cannot speak for other browsers though.

Comment: `view-source` works for me in Firefox 36, too.

Comment: Yes its working in Firefox 36, but not in IE 11. Firefox does not seem to initiate a new GET request when viewing source after it has rendered the webpage. Could someone who knows the internal workings of Firefox please corroborate that it is infact safe to directly use `view-source` in Firefox 36?

Comment: Since you cannot speak for other browsers, I would not say "it is absolutely safe".  And, IIRC, long ago I saw some browsers show HTML source of the page *after* JavaScript modified it.

Comment: @jamesdlin Edited the answer for even more clarity. Firefox shows the modified source after it has rendered the page since it does not initiate a new GET request to the server. I hope someone could corroborate that is not the case when directly using `view-source` from the address bar in Firefox 36

Comment: Also, "NoScript" is not guaranteed to prevent any scripting attacks. It's another piece of software; it has bugs. There may be exploits that target a bug in the browser, a bug in NoScript, or a combination to execute scripts without permission.

Comment: @Joseph: Can confirm: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ygExH.png

Comment: Sending a new GET request of course means the server could change the script between the two requests. So you can't know for sure if what you are seeing is what you will be running.

Comment: @Joseph @DragonLord Firefox loads the page from cache if it exists - but this is **not** the same as the rendered version. The only way to view the rendered version is through the HTML inspector. Tested by removing the body element from this page via JS and then navigating to this page by `view-source:` on a different tab, where said element was clearly still there. Actually, the context menu source browser doesn't show the rendered version either.

Comment: The browser will still redirect you if the response contains a `Location:` header, although you do still remain in "view-source" mode (tested Chrome).

Answer (score 22):

While it is **currently** safe on Chrome you should not base your future checks on that. Things may change anytime and I have not seen the lack of rendering as being a specifically documented feature.

If you want to look at the code, it is much better to download the page via a command-line tool ([curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) for instance) and analyze what was loaded and saved in a file. This also has the added value of easily testing various pages which may be possibly served in response to different User-Agents.

Comment: Of course, there is no guarantee of absense of bugs, so even curl might be unsafe for non-js reasons.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: this is not a matter of bugs: one day Google may decide that it will render the source in the `view-source` page (to make it dynamic, nicer, whatever). By downloading the page with a command-line downloader like `curl` you just issue a `GET` and save what is returned by the server in a file. There is no processing done because the job of `curl` is not to process anything (it is designed for that). You may have bugs in the implementation and have problems with some pages, but not security ones (as the attacks happen in whatever renders the page).

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with the other answers saying it is currently safe, there is a potential misunderstanding going on. You said you wanted to use it to check if a site is safe, so presumably you will load a page normally after you have found no malicious content when viewing the source. If this is true, then you must be aware that websites are able to detect (or at least infer) that you are using `view-source:`. Not only does it, on Firefox at least, not use the cache, resulting in it loading the page a second time, but it does not load other resources. If a site sees someone with a regular browser user agent connect but load no other resources, they can infer that the user is checking the source. It is simple to automate this detection and only serve malicious JavaScript from a resource in the case that it is loaded along with all the rest of the page. This would hide its presence from your inspection of the source, despite the website still serving malicious JavaScript to you.

A potential solution would be to use Inspect Element, which looks at the currently open page and allows for reading the source. This is much harder to detect (though not impossible, since CSS can determine the size of the browser window, which shrinks by a specific amount when inspect element is open). Inspect Element *is* more complex, and may be more exploitable than `view-source:`, so you must apply threat modeling in this situation.